# Spring-hibernate : How to solve HibernateException" DefaultSchemaNameResolver requires Dialect to provide MySQL5Dialect"

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, maven

I am newbie to Spring & Hibernate, 
Trying to run project that run them togethet. 
After a lot of error fixing the things work well, 
But when I'm running the main class I still get that exception :

```
org.hibernate.HibernateException: Use of DefaultSchemaNameResolver requires Dialect to provide the proper SQL statement/command but provided Dialect [org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL57Dialect] did not return anything from Dialect#getCurrentSchemaCommand
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.DefaultSchemaNameResolver$SchemaNameResolverFallbackDelegate.resolveSchemaName(DefaultSchemaNameResolver.java:100) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.1.Final.jar:5.3.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.DefaultSchemaNameResolver.resolveSchemaName(DefaultSchemaNameResolver.java:76) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.1.Final.jar:5.3.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentImpl.determineCurrentSchemaName(JdbcEnvironmentImpl.java:298) [hibernate-core-5.3.1.Final.jar:5.3.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentImpl.<init>(JdbcEnvironmentImpl.java:232) [hibernate-core-5.3.1.Final.jar:5.3.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:114) [hibernate-core-5.3.1.Final.jar:5.3.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:35) [hibernate-core-5.3.1.Final.jar:5.3.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:94) [hibernate-core-5.3.1.Final.jar:5.3.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:263) [hibernate-core-5.3.1.Final.jar:5.3.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:237) [hibernate-core-5.3.1.Final.jar:5.3.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214) [hibernate-core-5.3.1.Final.jar:5.3.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.id.factory.internal.DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.injectServices(DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.java:152) [hibernate-core-5.3.1.Final.jar:5.3.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.injectDependencies(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:286) [hibernate-core-5.3.1.Final.jar:5.3.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:243) [hibernate-core-5.3.1.Final.jar:5.3.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214) [hibernate-core-5.3.1.Final.jar:5.3.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.<init>(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:179) [hibernate-core-5.3.1.Final.jar:5.3.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:119) [hibernate-core-5.3.1.Final.jar:5.3.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.build(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:84) [hibernate-core-5.3.1.Final.jar:5.3.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:474) [hibernate-core-5.3.1.Final.jar:5.3.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:85) [hibernate-core-5.3.1.Final.jar:5.3.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:689) [hibernate-core-5.3.1.Final.jar:5.3.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:724) [hibernate-core-5.3.1.Final.jar:5.3.1.Final]
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBuilder.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBuilder.java:343) [spring-orm-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:431) [spring-orm-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:416) [spring-orm-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1637) [spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574) [spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545) [spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) [spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) [spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) [spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) [spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) [spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:753) [spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:839) [spring-context-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:538) [spring-context-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139) [spring-context-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83) [spring-context-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
at springboot.beans.app.SpringHibernateMain.main(SpringHibernateMain.java:24) [classes/:na]
```

Trying google it, to remove the dialect property, or change it, but it's not work.

What is the cause of it, and how to fix (also getting a lot of warnings ate the pom.xml about versions overriding).

This is the relevant files, I hope:

The running class:

```
    package springboot.beans.app;

import java.util.List;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;
import org.hibernate.boot.Metadata;
import org.hibernate.boot.MetadataSources;
import org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistry;
import org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

import database.ManageEmployee;
import withAnnotation.InsertRecords;
import withAnnotation.InsertRecords2;
import withAnnotation.Product;


    public class SpringHibernateMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ClassPathXmlApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("SpringHibernateConfiguration.xml");

        ManageEmployee manager = context.getBean(ManageEmployee.class);
        /* Add few employee records in database */
          Integer empID1 = manager.addEmployee("Spring222", "TODAY222", 30000);
          Integer empID2 = manager.addEmployee("Avraham-spring", "Das", 5000);
          Integer empID3 = manager.addEmployee("Sarah wigh spring", "Paul", 10000);

          /* List down all the employees */
          manager.listEmployees();

          /* Update employee's records */
          manager.updateEmployee(empID1, 5000);
          System.out.println(empID2 + " = empID2");
          /* Delete an employee from the database */
          manager.deleteEmployee(empID2);

          /* List down new list of the employees */
          manager.listEmployees();

          InsertRecords2 producer = context.getBean(InsertRecords2.class);
          producer.updateProducts();//it's running insertion from inside 


            System.out.println("check if done");


        //close resources
        context.close();    
    }
    }
```

The SpringHibernateConfiguration.xml :

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.0.xsd">

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
        destroy-method="close">
        <!-- <property name = "hibernate.connection.driver_class">
         com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
      </property>
        -->
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hibernate_mysql7?useSSL=false" />
        <property name="username" value="XXXX" />
        <property name="password" value="XXXX" />
    </bean>

<!-- Hibernate 3 XML SessionFactory Bean definition-->
<!--    <bean id="hibernate3SessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="mappingResources">
            <list>
                <value>person.hbm.xml</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <value>
                hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
            </value>
        </property>
    </bean> -->

<!-- Hibernate 4 Annotation SessionFactory Bean definition-->
    <bean id="hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="annotatedClasses"><!-- sessionFactory -->
            <list>
                <!-- <value>Employee.hbm.xml</value> ? <value>database.Employee</value> -->
                <value>withAnnotation.Product</value>

            </list>


        </property>
        <!-- add this -->
         <property name="mappingResources">
            <list>
            <value>Employee.hbm.xml</value>
            </list>
        </property>

        <!-- end -->
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
            <!--  this cause new creating and clean all from the past 
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</prop>
            if u want to create once and keep use that instead :--> 
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
            <!-- hibernate found it by itself  <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</prop> --> 
                <prop key="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop><!-- <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</property> -->

            </props>
        </property>

    </bean>



    <bean id="managerEmployee" class="database.ManageEmployee">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="producer" class="withAnnotation.InsertRecords2">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

the pom.xml :

```
<

project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>springboot.beans.app</groupId>
  <artifactId>SpringHibernateBasic5-OtherConfiguration</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>SpringHibernateBasic5-OtherConfiguration</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <spring.version>4.2.7.RELEASE</spring.version>
     <java.version>1.8</java.version>
     <spring-framework.version>4.0.3.RELEASE</spring-framework.version>
     <!-- *** added  -->
    <!-- Hibernate / JPA -->
        <!-- <hibernate.version>4.3.5.Final</hibernate.version> -->
        <hibernate.version>5.3.1.Final</hibernate.version> <!--   3.6.9.Final-->

        <!-- Logging -->
        <logback.version>1.0.13</logback.version>
        <slf4j.version>1.7.5</slf4j.version>

  </properties>
  <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.5.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

  <dependencies>
   <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version><!--$NO-MVN-MAN-VER$-->
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring boot dependencies -->
       <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>


    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring ORM support -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Logging with SLF4J & LogBack -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <version>${logback.version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Hibernate -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.47</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>



    <!-- Spring dependency -->


    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>



  </dependencies>

  <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>



        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

The full log of the running is long , so what I need to copy here ?

Comment: For starters remove the `hibernate.current_session_context_class` that stops proper tx management from Spring. And Spring 4.2 doesn't support hibernate 5.3. You are using Hibernate 4 support classes to configure hibernate 5 (obviously not going to work). You are mixing versions of Spring and finally you are apparently trying to use spring boot (although your code doesn't show it) with an incompatible spring version. All in all I have no idea what you are trying but it isn't going to work.

Comment: So I to organize it ?

Answer (score 2):

There are several things flawed in your approach

1. Mixing 3 different Spring versions (5.0, 4.2 and 4.0)
2. Using a hibernate version that isn't supported by Spring 4
3. Use Hibernate 4 support classes to configure hibernate 5
4. Tried to use Spring Boot, stepped back and worked around it
5. Use Hibernate instead of JPA and Hibernate as the JPA provider

First of all clean up your `pom.xml` and use Spring Boots dependency management to your advantage.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>springboot.beans.app</groupId>
  <artifactId>SpringHibernateBasic5-OtherConfiguration</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <name>SpringHibernateBasic5-OtherConfiguration</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
  </properties>

  <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.5.RELEASE</version>
  </parent>

  <dependencies>
    <!-- Spring boot dependencies -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>mysql</groupId>
      <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>      
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

Notice that most of your dependencies are gone as most of them are already managed by one of the starters you had (slf4j, logback, Spring dependencies). You want to use Hibernate (and I suggest to use JPA instead of plain hibernate) it is enough to add `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa` to get all the needed dependencies.

Next create an `application.properties` in `src/main/resources` and put the following in there (deducted from your question).

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hibernate_mysql7?useSSL=false
spring.datasource.username=XXXX
spring.datasource.password=XXXX

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```

This will configure the datasource and create the schema (although you are better not to use that in production!).

Now modify your `SpringHibernateMain` and put an `@SpringBootApplication` annotation on it and change your `main` method. Also place your entities in a proper sub package.

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringHibernateMain {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    ApplicationContext context = SpringApplication.run(SpringHibernateMain.class ,args);

    ManageEmployee manager = context.getBean(ManageEmployee.class);
   /* Add few employee records in database */
    Integer empID1 = manager.addEmployee("Spring222", "TODAY222", 30000);
    Integer empID2 = manager.addEmployee("Avraham-spring", "Das", 5000);
    Integer empID3 = manager.addEmployee("Sarah wigh spring", "Paul", 10000);

       /* List down all the employees */
    manager.listEmployees();

    /* Update employee's records */
    manager.updateEmployee(empID1, 5000);
    System.out.println(empID2 + " = empID2");
    /* Delete an employee from the database */
    manager.deleteEmployee(empID2);

    /* List down new list of the employees */
    manager.listEmployees();

    InsertRecords2 producer = context.getBean(InsertRecords2.class);
    producer.updateProducts();//it's running insertion from inside 


    System.out.println("check if done");
  }
}
```

Now place the `SpringHibernateMain` in a decent package like `springboot.beans.app` (as you had) and place the entities in `springboot.beans.app.entities` and everything else in `springboot.beans.app.services` (instead of what you have now).

The thing left for you is to "rewrite" your classes `InsertRecords2` and `ManageEmployee` to use the `EntityManager` instead of the plain `SessionFactory`. It will still use Hibernate underneath but generally it is better to use JPA and only plain Hibernate in those cases you really need.

Comment: Thanks for the extended answer. I am trying to do that. 
Guess that  "rewrite" your classes InsertRecords2 and ManageEmployee to use the EntityManager", Include some chage that I need to implement (and learn), because now I am getting error : 

No qualifying bean of type 'springboot.beans.springBoot.services.ManageEmployee' available

Comment: You aren't using XML anymore (although you could I wouldn't recommend it). Annotate the class with `@Service` or `@Component` or in the case you do dataacess you might be better of with `@Repository` instead.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it. 
You have any tips/suggestion about what to study and how to be professional in Spring-Hibernate for today ? What approach to adapt, which versions, and recommended documentation ?

Comment: And why do it's recommended to do it in that structure? If I want to make other structure ?

Comment: Because that way spring boot will automatically detect all the beans.